# Store arbitrary json in CosmosDB posted into api endpoint

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, system.text.json, minimal-apis

I'm trying to save *semi* arbitrary json to CosmosDb

I say *semi* because the start of the json will have some known properties. For example:

```
{
    "id": "88e37e40-fd7e-478e-9ac5-140601fcddad",
    "type": "http",
    "name": "request1",
    "body": {
        "property1" : 1,
        "otherProperty": "foo"
    }
}
```

As you can see, `body` is the arbitrary part.

`id` and `type` and `name` are for demo purposes, but we could need to validate these properties.

Here's what I'm trying

```
app.MapPost
(
    "/", async (HttpRequest httpRequest, Container db) =>
    {
        var postedRequest = await httpRequest
            .ReadFromJsonAsync<Request>();

        var id = postedRequest.id;
        var type = postedRequest.type;

        var savedItem = await db.CreateItemAsync(postedRequest, new PartitionKey(type));

        return Results.Created($"/requests/{type}/{id}", savedItem.Resource);
    }
);

public record Request(string id, string type, string name, dynamic body);
```

My problem is when I POST the example json at the top of this question, it's being persisted like so:

```
{
    "id": "88e37e40-fd7e-478e-9ac5-140601fcddad",
    "type": "http",
    "name": "request1"
    "body": {
        "ValueKind": 1
    },

    "_rid": "WxgaAN+DhzoBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/WxgaAA==/colls/WxgaAN+Dhzo=/docs/WxgaAN+DhzoBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-96ae-5ccf928801d8\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1657712863
}
```

It's using ValueKind in place of the arbitrary json. I believe this is because of how the framework is deserializing it, perhaps due to my usage of `dynamic`

Is there another type is should use?  Or perhaps deserialize HttpRequest body to a stream first, then probe the properties I am interested in validating them? Using Utf8JsonReader? I'm not sure where to go from here.

---

**Here's my full code**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using CosmosClient client = new("<connectionstring>");
Database database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(
    id: "testing"
);
Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(
    id: "requests",
    partitionKeyPath: "/type",
    throughput: 400
);

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Container>(container);

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Started");

app.MapPost
(
    "/", async (HttpRequest httpRequest, Container db) =>
    {
        var postedRequest = await httpRequest
            .ReadFromJsonAsync<Request>();

        var id = postedRequest.id;
        var type = postedRequest.type;

        var savedItem = await db.CreateItemAsync(postedRequest, new PartitionKey(type));

        return Results.Created($"/requests/{type}/{id}", savedItem.Resource);
    }
);

app.MapGet
(
    "/requests/{type}/{id}", (Container db, string type, string id) =>
    {
        var dbResult = db.ReadItemAsync<Request>(id, new PartitionKey(type));

        return Results.Ok(dbResult);
    }
);

app.Run();

public record Request(string id, string type, string name, dynamic body);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can know the Partition Key (it comes in the url for example), then it would be simpler to use the Stream APIs. Example: https://github.com/ealsur/ondotnet-cosmosdb/tree/master/src/episode1/streams#streams

```
app.MapPost
(
    "/{type}/{id}", async (string type, string id, HttpRequest httpRequest, Container db) =>
    {
        var savedItem = await db.CreateItemStreamAsync(httpRequest.Body, new PartitionKey(type));

        return Results.Stream(savedItem.Content, "application/json");
    }
);
```